# com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread(18): EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: react-native

I Got an error when run application a few minutes.

Error Msg:(3 Threads trace)

- thread #1: tid = 0x7940d5, 0x0000000110b58c96 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread'

  - frame #0: 0x0000000110b58c96 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000110b580d7 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
    frame #2: 0x000000010d69cb64 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
    frame #3: 0x000000010d69bfbf CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1295
    frame #4: 0x000000010d69b828 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #5: 0x0000000112854ad2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #6: 0x000000010f1db610 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
    frame #7: 0x000000010c0e6cff JJTest`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff53b19668) + 111 at main.m:16
    frame #8: 0x000000011081e92d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #9: 0x000000011081e92d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
- thread #16: tid = 0x795b43, 0x000000010c968d10 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 16, name = 'com.squareup.SocketRocket.NetworkThread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

  - frame #0: 0x000000010c968d10 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 16
    frame #1: 0x000000010c968d4a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_storeStrong + 32
    frame #2: 0x000000010c1f28d1 JJTest`__copy_helper_block_((null)=0x00007f92cd0f81a0, (null)=0x0000700000739ae8) + 113 at RCTSRWebSocket.m:0
    frame #3: 0x000000011086159d libsystem_blocks.dylib`_Block_copy_internal + 325
    frame #4: 0x00000001107c9e45 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_Block_copy + 43
    frame #5: 0x00000001107cdb4a libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_async + 57
    frame #6: 0x000000010c1f1c0b JJTest`-[RCTSRWebSocket stream:handleEvent:](self=0x00007f92cd2f1de0, _cmd="stream:handleEvent:", aStream=0x00007f92cd237020, eventCode=NSStreamEventErrorOccurred) + 1611 at RCTSRWebSocket.m:1351
    frame #7: 0x000000010d6e4a44 CoreFoundation`_signalEventSync + 180
    frame #8: 0x000000010d718d4e CoreFoundation`_cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 478
    frame #9: 0x000000010d6a6a31 CoreFoundation`**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    frame #10: 0x000000010d69c95c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    frame #11: 0x000000010d69be13 CoreFoundation`**CFRunLoopRun + 867
    frame #12: 0x000000010d69b828 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #13: 0x000000010c5422f1 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
    frame #14: 0x000000010c1f3af8 JJTest`-[_RCTSRRunLoopThread main](self=0x00007f92caeb7d30, _cmd="main") + 376 at RCTSRWebSocket.m:1620
    frame #15: 0x000000010c5dfdfb Foundation`__NSThread__start** + 1198
    frame #16: 0x0000000110b229b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #17: 0x0000000110b2292e libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 168
    frame #18: 0x0000000110b20385 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
- thread #162: tid = 0x7d2897, 0x0000000110b58c96 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, name = 'com.facebook.React.JavaScript'

  - frame #0: 0x0000000110b58c96 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000110b580d7 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 55
    frame #2: 0x000000010d69cb64 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
    frame #3: 0x000000010d69bfbf CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1295
    frame #4: 0x000000010d69b828 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #5: 0x000000010c14a84b JJTest`+[RCTContextExecutor runRunLoopThread](self=RCTContextExecutor, _cmd="runRunLoopThread") + 363 at RCTContextExecutor.m:284
    frame #6: 0x000000010c5dfdfb Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 1198
    frame #7: 0x0000000110b229b1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #8: 0x0000000110b2292e libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 168
    frame #9: 0x0000000110b20385 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

RN: 0.17.0

Comment: I got this too running an app for a while in the iOS Simulator. Did you manage to solve it? I'm under RN 0.20..

Comment: @amb  In url address append "&dev=false" . This error has not appear.  see [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5198#issuecomment-184839978)

Comment: Best to upvote at Product Pains: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/crash-in-rctsrwebsocketm

Comment: This is fixed in this commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/dd209bb7891ed5f05b96a9922c7b0e39bf3ac9e9